# Vector operation analogous to polynomial multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Given that the set of all univariate polynomials of degree up to $n$ forms a vector space, addition and scalar multiplication between polynomials is, by definition, analogous to that of vectors.

Is there some kind of extension of this definition of a vector space that introduces a vector operation that is analogous to polynomial multiplication?

I am cautious when asking this question since such an operation could result in a vector with more elements than the operands, which feels difficult to handle (for lack of a better phrase).

Some context: when writing software that handles polynomials, I am under the impression that they are usually represented as a vector (or other array-like data structure) of coefficients. Given this, the implementation of polynomial addition and scalar multiplication is just a matter of performing the basic operations on the underlying coefficient vector of the polynomial. Somewhat surprisingly, this does not seem to be the case for polynomial multiplication.

Comment: For multiplying polynomials, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for the reference! It led me to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) which gave me my answer.